# Not able to play audio pcm wav stream in ipad, iphone browser

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

Web App which supports desktop, tablet and mobile. 
Issue:
Not able to play below mentioned audio wav stream in iphone/ipad safari browsers

1. 8000 hz, 16 bit, mono, signed
2. 8000 hz, 16 bit, stereo, signed

Added below header into the audio wav stream
content-type: "audio/x-wav"
    .header("Content-Length", ""+rawAudio.length)
    .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
    .header("Last-Modified", "Wed, 27 Nov 2013 16:40:59 GMT")
    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")

Wav as a stream: a get restful api returns binarystream as a response with the above mentioned header.

```
sample restful: /audio/getWav.do (this is an spring based web app, which returns binary wav stream as response)
```

Options tried, but did not work:
1. web audio api, called audio.play() function on_touch_start
2. jplayer to play wav stream
3. jquery.mb.audio API to play wav stream

Option worked:
1. upload the wav file into web app, iphone/ipad play the file.

why is that ipad/iphone safari browser plays the wav file from the web server, but does not play the wav stream.

Pls provide inputs or pointers to play wav stream in iphone or ipad.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.kehlet.cx/articles/156.html